# Can't get data from controller using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Am I missing something here? I just want an alert box to give me the string value in my controller action.
I keep getting the internal server error message in dev tools

```
        public JsonResult Button_Click()
        {
            string cam = "Hello";

            return Json(cam, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

```
        $("#hello").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Mycontroller/Button_Click/',
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                failure: function () {
                    alert("FAIL");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("ERROR");
                }
            });
        });   
    });
```

I should just get an alert box with "Hello" in it.

Comment: Side note: `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` can be removed. A GET request doesn't have any body content, so therefore it cannot (meaningfully) have a content type, either.

Comment: Anyway, if you get an Internal Server Error it means somewhere your ASP.NET application crashed. You need to step through it with the debugger, and/or check event logs on the server to see if it logged an underlying exception, which would give you more information.

Comment: Try without the underscore in the method name & ajax url call.

Comment: @JasonRoner why? Underscores are perfectly valid in URLs

Comment: So, internal server error in ajax calls could also mean that you are hitting on a wrong endpoint. Try using `'@Url.Action("Button_Click", "MyController")'`

Comment: Also, I can't see the `[HttpGet]` attribute decorated on the `Button_Click` method.

Comment: hey bro, your code is absolute correct  so pls check your iis or your code

Comment: I changed the type to a "POST" and I added the [HttpPost] above my controller method and it still doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing 'Mycontroller' write only 'My'. 'Controller' suffix is not required.

This should Work

Javascript:

```
                $("#hello").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/My/Button_Click/',
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    failure: function () {
                        alert("FAIL");
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("ERROR");
                    }
                });
            });
```

Action:

```
public JsonResult Button_Click()
    {
        string cam = "Hello";

        return Json(cam, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

HTML:

```
<span id="hello">Click Me</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was experimenting and it looks like this is working for me:

```
return new JsonResult(){ Data=cam, JsonRequestBehavior=JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
```

Instead of:

```
return Json(cam, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

As for an explanation, I don't have one [yet].  Strangely, using Post instead of Get in Ajax works fine the old way.  I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

your server side code is correct but in javascript you added extra braces,

if i have tried and works fine just remove extra `)};` after remove this your script look likes

```
$("#hello").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Mycontroller/Button_Click/',
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                failure: function () {
                    alert("FAIL");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("ERROR");
                }
            });
     });
```

i hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public JsonResult Button_Click()
            {
                string cam = "Hello";

          return Json(new { result = true,data=cam }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            }



      $("#hello").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Mycontroller/Button_Click/',
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType:'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (result) {
                          if(result.result==true)
                          {
                            alert(result.data);
                          } 
                    },
                    failure: function () {
                        alert("FAIL");
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("ERROR");
                    }
                });
            });   
        });

you return direct data so your data not display 
my changes help you
```

Comment: How would this prevent an Internal Server Error exactly?

Comment: i am only see what output he want so i don't see his question and i quickly response i think this solution work for them. Now i think Content-type remove for in this case **contentType: 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',**

Comment: No-one asked for the output changes you suggested though. That isn't in the question. He just wants a simple string. Yes you can remove the content type, it's not useful because a GET request does not contain a body, so there is no content anyway.

Comment: i am said remove content type **contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",** and replace with am write in upper comments like **contentType: 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'**

Comment: Sorry, I mis-read your comment, but perhaps that's because your suggestion is so strange. Why would XML be useful here? Do you see XML in OP's code? Like I said, the GET request does not send any body content, so specifying a content type does not make any sense. Are you just guessing, or did you have some kind of reason for suggesting it?

Comment: i think because he send text format so i refer to this.

Comment: 1) he's not sending text. Actually he's not sending **anything**. For the 3rd time: **a GET request does not have a body to contain any content.** 2) regardless of that, XML is a text format but plain text is not XML. JSON is also a text format. So if you're concerned about text then changing from XML to JSON wouldn't alter anything

Comment: OK Thank you for advise and user code absolute right so i don't know how he gets error but i suggest my code so

Comment: Actually if the code was totally correct then probably there wouldn't be an issue. I think jamshaid kamran's comments above may be relevant to the issue. Just waiting for OP to confirm if they tried it